# Visually diff very large files

Tags: xml, diff, large-files

I have two XML files which I would like to visually diff. They both have approximately 145,000 lines in them. Windiff is dying on me when I attempt to do this.

Is there some other application that can handle this kind of file size?

Comment: print them out, overlay the pages, and hold them up to the light? just joking, but what do you mean by "visually diff"?

Comment: I need to find differences in the files. I know there are a whole lot, but I'm specifically looking for huge chunks that are missing. The easiest way to do this is to do it visually.

Comment: OK. One thing I've used is ImageMagick, converting every byte into a pixel of an image. Weird, I know, but it works under some circumstances. Good for visualizing patterns, but probably not useful in this context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've heard good things about [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/), give it a spin to see if it works for you, it has a 30 day free trial.

Answer (score 1):

I can recomend [Project: Merge](http://www.projectmerge.com). We use it to compare/merge visual studio project files...

> Project: Merge is a Windows® application for comparing and merging XML files. Comparing two or three XML files with each other allows you to see what's changed, while merging allows you to integrate the differences from the input files into a single output file.

The good thing with Project: Merge is that it is XML-aware (i.e. it is not only a text diff tool like winmerge or beyond compare)

Answer (score 1):

There's a product called DeltaXML that's designed for this purpose.

http://www.deltaxml.com/

It may do more than you want, and cost more than you want, but it's certainly up to the task.